# Menu covering header

Tags: html, css, menu, header

My menu background is covering header and content (those tables) when you make your browser smaller (its responsive menu). How do I make it so that header and tables will move down a bit so its not hidden behind menu bg?

HTML: https://paste.ee/p/ww1CT

CSS:  https://paste.ee/p/TEmU5

Comment: http://responsive-nav.com/

Comment: Please copy your code on the question. Those links can dissappear at any time leaving the rest of the people with the same question equally frustrated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
nav {    
  position:fixed;
 }
```

make it sit relative to the other content

```
nav {    
  position:relative;
 }
```

Comment: I need it to be fixed, because its moving when you are scrolling